# Internet Explorer 9 Object Detection

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, object-detection, capability

I am searching for an object detection capability check which will identify IE9. Can you help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out [this snippet](https://gist.github.com/527683) by [James Padolsey](http://james.padolsey.com/):

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------
// A short snippet for detecting versions of IE in JavaScript
// without resorting to user-agent sniffing
// ----------------------------------------------------------
// If you're not in IE (or IE version is less than 5) then:
//     ie === undefined
// If you're in IE (>=5) then you can determine which version:
//     ie === 7; // IE7
// Thus, to detect IE:
//     if (ie) {}
// And to detect the version:
//     ie === 6 // IE6
//     ie > 7 // IE8, IE9 ...
//     ie < 9 // Anything less than IE9
// ----------------------------------------------------------

// UPDATE: Now using Live NodeList idea from @jdalton

var ie = (function(){

    var undef,
        v = 3,
        div = document.createElement('div'),
        all = div.getElementsByTagName('i');

    while (
        div.innerHTML = '<!--[if gt IE ' + (++v) + ']><i></i><![endif]-->',
        all[0]
    );

    return v > 4 ? v : undef;

}());
```

Afterwards, you could use it like this:

```
if (ie == 9) {
  // It’s IE9!
  // Insert your code here
}
```

The good thing here is that it doesn’t sniff the UA string (which, in itself, is unreliable) — instead, it uses conditional comments, which work reliably in IE.

This can be used to detect IE5—9.

Comment: when i test it in ie9 it gives me "7".

Comment: +1 for this, which is what I would have posted and seems not that well-known. One thing to note is that IE 10 will not support conditional comments, so this trick will not work in future versions of IE (see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/07/06/html5-parsing-in-ie10.aspx)

Comment: @FURKANILGIN: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8187346/html-conditional-statement-hack-sees-ie-as-wrong-version-when-live

Comment: @TimDown Yeah, I did mention in the post that it can be used to detect IE5–9 — but that may have been too subtle.

Comment: @MathiasBynens: I saw that but thought the point needed spelling out. So yes, too subtle :)

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure this is what you're asking, but if you want to detect information about the browser of the visitor you can do check `navigator.appVersion`

Example:

```
<div id="example"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

txt = "<p>Browser CodeName: " + navigator.appCodeName + "</p>";
txt+= "<p>Browser Name: " + navigator.appName + "</p>";
txt+= "<p>Browser Version: " + navigator.appVersion + "</p>";
txt+= "<p>Cookies Enabled: " + navigator.cookieEnabled + "</p>";
txt+= "<p>Platform: " + navigator.platform + "</p>";
txt+= "<p>User-agent header: " + navigator.userAgent + "</p>";

document.getElementById("example").innerHTML=txt;

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the properties of the [IE window object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535873(v=vs.85).aspx) introduced in each release to distinguish IE versions:

- IE >= 7: `("onpropertychange" in document) && (!!window.XMLHttpRequest)`
- IE >= 8: `("onpropertychange" in document) && (!!window.XDomainRequest)`
- IE >= 9: `("onpropertychange" in document) && (!!window.innerWidth)`
- IE >= 10: `("onpropertychange" in document) && (!!window.matchMedia)`
- IE >= 11: `(!!window.msMatchMedia) && (!window.doScroll)`